# How to define a truth set that is the entire domain in logic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I just have a question regarding how to define a truth set for the following:
Suppose the domain is all integers Z, and the statement is true for all integers in the domain.

How would i define the truth set?
The way i have been writing them is {x E Z| x = 2k} - example for even integers.
But i am not sure how you would define all of the domain.

thanks heaps
Corey :)

Comment: Well, there's always $\{x\in\mathbb{Z}:x=x\}$.

Comment: @Malice Vidrine: always? if equality is not in the language?

Comment: @Carl: There's an element of hyperbole in my comment to be sure, but I find it to be warranted as FOL with equality is more the rule than the exception.

Comment: Now about just writing "$\mathbb Z$"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about $\{x: x=x\}$? (Or, making the domain explicit, $\{x\in D: x=x\}$.)

Comment: Equality may not be in the language, but if $\phi$ is a tautology then $\{x : \phi\}$ will work. As long as the language has negation and disjunction, or the equivalent, there will be tautologies such as $\psi \lor \lnot \psi$.

Comment: Equality is always in the language! :P